# How can i crop image using C#

Tags: c#, image-manipulation

I have a picture of document taken from camera. 
Now what i have to do is crop only document from that image . 
Please can anyone suggest me how best it can be done or first is it possible or not

Edit

For more information .. my next question
[How to get edge coordinates of a image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890422/how-to-get-edge-coordinates-of-a-image)

Comment: Are you asking how you can automatically find the boundaries/edges of the document within the photo?

Comment: yes... once finding the boundries .. i need to crop that document image from its parent image .. i hope could able to explain it

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but this is written in C# and seems to do basic edge detection: http://www.gutgames.com/post/Edge-detection-in-C.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you know the area that contains the image data you would like to crop, you could use this article from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752345.aspx

If you need to find the relevant area before cropping, you need to investigate some image processing techniques. e.g. [Corner Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection)

Comment: Very nice suggestion with `CroppedImage`.  I wasn't aware of such capability with WPF.

Comment: Thanks Weichsel ... 
Let me look into it

Comment: Weichsel ... 
I am considering the approach suggested by you ... 
Need one help do u know where i can find implementation of Corner detection algorithm....or Canny algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

In the assumption you are performing preprocessing for OCR, I would look into using the [Aforge Framework](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) if possible.

There is a specific set of functions in the Imaging classes for preforming crops and any other related manipulations(image rotation, hue adjustment, brightness/contrast adjustment, filter noise, etc) that you might need.

Answer (score 0):

Two links for you

http://google.com/search?q=c%23+crop+bitmap and http://www.nerdydork.com/crop-an-image-bitmap-in-c-or-vbnet.html

Comment: Would you change the tinyURL to the full URL lest they will lead me to NSFW pages at work.

Comment: Posting Let Me Google That For You links isn't particularly helpful

Comment: @ChrisF: Not helpful, but funny.