# How to get edge coordinates of a image?

Tags: c#, image

i posted a question regarding croping an image present in a parent image.
[How can i crop image using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889306/how-can-i-crop-image-using-c)
I've detected the Image edge using one of the online algorithms, now i need to get the coordinates of the corners. How can i get the corner coordinates so i can fetch the image from its parent?

The Image is taken with a camera, and has contains a picture of a document. I need to find that document and crop it out of the parent image.

Comment: which approach did you use finally?

Answer (score 2):

In the other [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889306/how-can-i-crop-image-using-c), a number of corner detection algorithms were included.  I've been experimenting with the [AForge filters](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/corner_detectors.html) for corner detection, or the Hough line transform combined with a canny edge detector to pick out the image edges.